# Typo3 page properties / edit site causes Exception "Call to a member function getOption() on null"

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.7.x

first some additional info:

- Error thrown in file .../typo3conf/ext/fluidpages/Classes/Service/PageService.php in line 226.
- Typo3 8.7.9 , same error on dev-server and live-server
- I'm working (for first time) with an extension-based template, so maybe I ruined something inside the template folders, like Resources/Private/Templates/Page, [similar observation here (german)](http://www.typo3forum.net/discussion/80789/fehlermeldung-call-to-a-member-function-getoption-on-null).

This error is discussed in some other posts on other sites, e.g.:
[fluidpages at github](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidpages/issues/198), fix should be mainly clearing all caches (like in one or two other posts), not working for me;
 [fluid vhs at github](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/issues/1317), is a year old, can't imagine it's still not fixed and nobody else stumbled upon.
[In this post](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidpages/issues/356) there is a screenshot showing exactly the same detailed backtrace like my system.

I have no idea how to fix or even debug this, any hint is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the mistake and fix.

Mistake:

I used FLUIDTEMPLATES to include some static HTML in the head, and I put the respective fluid template into the folder typo3conf/ext/mytemplateextension/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/. This folder contains templates for the backend layouts, but mine wasn't.

Fix:

I made a new folder "Head" beneath "Page" and moved the disruptive template there and, of course, edited the path to this template in the according TS.

And the error is gone.